# CmisObjectNotFound ephesoft export to Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis, ephesoft

I'm using Ephesoft-Community-Edition-2.4.0.7 with alfresco 4.0
I got CmisObjectNotFoundException when i try to export uploaded file with meta-data.

this is the log in dcma-all.log

```
- batchInstanceIdentifierIdentifier : BI16  inputFileName : BI16_batch.xml  outputFileName : PRE_STATE_BI16_batch.xml
 - Successfully copy of the file for batch Instance identifier : BI16
- CMIS export plugin.
- Initializing properties...
- CMIS: HTTP Basic Authentication will be used for CMIS messaging.
Determining if the target folder "Sites" exists within the repository folder "/".
   - Folder already present
   - Found the child folder. Its folder ID is workspace://SpacesStore/383973c1-0325-408f-8f54-551c9bd86ebc.
   - Determining if the target folder "ephesoftintegration" exists within the repository folder "/Sites".
   - Folder already present
   - Found the child folder. Its folder ID is workspace://SpacesStore/5c4c7e20-7148-4c59-a3a8-edd76748aa3d.
   - Determining if the target folder "documentLibrary" exists within the repository folder "/Sites/ephesoftintegration".
   - Folder already present
   - Found the child folder. Its folder ID is workspace://SpacesStore/9ecc0217-4e5f-456a-b22c-9cb8b57a4152.
   - Determining if the target folder "files" exists within the repository folder "/Sites/ephesoftintegration/documentLibrary".
   - Folder already present
   - Found the child folder. Its folder ID is workspace://SpacesStore/32469808-a4cc-4cf9-acf4-2ab8e9a892a6.
   - Content mime type is: application/pdf
   - property - keyString : MyDocType , property-value : my:document
   - {cmis:objectTypeId=my:document, cmis:name=BI16_documentDOC1.pdf}
2016-01-16 16:07:43,662 ERROR  - Introuvable
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException: Introuvable
```

Comment: could you add also the alfresco log?

Comment: Have you checked if the file that it is trying to get exists in that folder and can be accessed by Alfresco?

Comment: thanks marco, i will post the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with Alfresco with (Enabled Versioning on files).
Any file created must have a document_versioning_state (MINOR OR MAJOR), it could not be NONE as default.

So the Solution is to modify in Ephesoft dcma-cmis.properties File located under  C:\Ephesoft\Application\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\dcma-cmis Folder.

This line must be

```
cmis.document_versioning_state=MAJOR
```